# templated codes works fine under G++ but error under VC++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Here are the codes, which work fine under `g++`, but give error under `VC++ 2014`:

```
template <class A>
struct Expression 
{
public:
    static const int status = A::status_;
}; 

struct Foo : public Expression<Foo>
{
    static const int  status_ = 0;
};

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Why ? Thanks!

The error messages are:

> error C2039: 'status_': is not a member of 'Foo'
>
> error C2065: 'status_': undeclared identifier
>
> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

Comment: Clang and ICC both reject this code, too. Presumably, GCC is simply not instantiating the template(s) because you do not use them at all. Its optimizer is quite smart; it knows all the code does is `return 0`.

Comment: @CodyGray I guess `A` is an incomplete type within `Expression`, so it's not a matter of *"smart"* optimization, or is it?

Comment: @piotr Well, I'd say it is quite smart if it realizes that none of the templates are used and elides the whole mess, simply transforming the program into the `main` function. Your mileage may vary. :-)

Comment: every optimization should follow the "[as if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)" rule, so talking about optimizations when the question is about code validity is misleading at best.

Comment: Not sure what I am missing. The optimizer ripping all the template code out is 100% in compliance with the "as if" rule.  @bolov The point is that if you never use the templates, the compiler is well within its rights to never have a discussion with you about their invalidity.

Comment: The code still works in gcc if `Foo` gets used: http://ideone.com/Jg9ggF (I replaced `const` with `constexpr`, but both cases work.)

Comment: gcc doesn't try to "resolve" Expression<T>::status until it's actually referenced somewhere, so it has no problems instantiating just the bare template declaration, for the purpose of defining the superclass. Hence, no error. VC appears to want to define the entire class. I am only going to guess that gcc's behavior is correct, and is consistent with how other aspects of templates should work.

Comment: I can reference both `status` and `status_` just fine using GCC: http://ideone.com/C1oVNu

Comment: The real question is: is this standard-conform? If so, then compileres rejecting this code are actually erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `status` and it will work. See below. As for standard, I do not know which compiler is correct.

```
template <class A>
struct Expression
{
public:
  static const int status;
};

struct Foo : public Expression<Foo>
{
  static const int  status_ = 0;
};

template< typename A >
const int Expression<A>::status = A::status_;

int main( void ) {
  return 0;
}
```